# NelmioApiDocBundle annotations for nested objects

Tags: php, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle

I am trying to add annotations for a model which has references of child nodes. But those child nodes are being called strings. The same code works just fine if it is referencing a different class. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

```
class Foo
{
    private int $id;
    /**
     * @OA\Property(
     *     type="array",
     *     @OA\Items(
     *         ref=@Model(type=Foo::class),
     *     )
     * ),
     * @var array<Foo>
     */
    private array $children;
}
```

Result

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "children": "string"
}
```

Expected

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "children": [{
    "id": 0,
    "children": [{}]
  }]
}
```